# Would season tags be useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, I'm halfway through the fourth season of *Fringe*. I like the series and I've asked some questions about it. I'd like to read and answer questions about it as well, however, from what I've seen before quickly looking the other way, is that even the titles can be spoilerific. And if the titles aren't, the questions themselves can be.

So what would help, is a way to see how far along a series a question is. For that purpose, I propose season tags: [season-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/season-1), [season-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/season-2) and so on. Having tags per show would be overkill, so yes, they would be meta tags, but they would be *useful* meta tags.

Along the same lines I can imagine [book-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-1), [book-2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-2) and so on.

Comment: Re: the book tags, I'm pretty certain we already have at least some installment specific tags for books in a series. What would be the benefit of using "book-1" over one of the existing tags?

Comment: We essentially have these tags already for series that aren't TV.  Books have individual title tags.  Films have individual movie tags.  And so on.  This issue stems from the way TV shows are treated as one monolithic work by our tagging system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A generic [season-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/season-1) tag would cause trouble with tag badges.  Consider the case where you have a gold [season-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/season-1) badge for, say, [doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who).  Now you've also got an instant dupe-hammer on [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) questions which are also tagged [season-1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/season-1).

So I'd say "no"; they may be useful for an immediate and specific class of question, but would in the longer term cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: Speaking of Doctor Who, _which_ [tag:season-1]?

Comment: I hadn't thought of gold badges and the powers that come with them. That makes this, and indeed any meta tags, a bad idea.